# Resolving global TypeScript types in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

In VSCode, I have a project structure a bit like this:

```
my-project
﹂client
  ﹂client.test.ts
  ﹂package.json
﹂server
  ﹂server.test.ts
  ﹂package.json
```

The `package.json` files contain dependencies for the tests including `jest` and `@types/jest`.

If I open one of the child folders directly (client or server), VSCode will show the test file with no errors as it can find all of the definitions for jest globals like `expect`, `describe` etc.

If I open the root of the project (my-project), VSCode shows errors in the test file, as it can no longer locate the type definitions for `jest`.

If I add a `package.json` at the root of my project and then add the jest types to it, VSCode is happy again.

Is there a setting I can change or some configuration that will allow VSCode to find the type definitions for jest globals from the root of the project, without needing to install them separately?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to manage a such project structure.

You could consider handling it as a *monorepo*: there are many tools to manage such monorepo, which in particular install common and compatible packages in the root `node_modules` folder. This specifically leverages [Node.js module resolution](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders), which looks for non-relative imports in all enclosing folders' `node_modules` directories:

```
my-project/
├── client/
│   ├── client.test.ts
│   └── package.json
├── node_modules/
├── server/
│   ├── package.json
│   └── server.test.ts
└── package.json
```

---

Another possible solution would be to configure a root `tsconfig.json` with [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) compiler option:

```
my-project/
├── client/
│   ├── node_modules/
│   ├── client.test.ts
│   └── package.json
├── server/
│   ├── node_modules/
│   ├── package.json
│   └── server.test.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./client/node_modules",
      "./client/node_modules/@types",
      "./server/node_modules",
      "./server/node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```